# Python sending dictionary through TCP

Tags: python, dictionary, tcp

I'm a python beginner, and I'm curious how can I send a dictionary through TCP

Comment: TCP is rather low-level, which means you have to know more about what you're doing to get it right. Something highlevel like a [simplexmlrpcserver](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) and [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) might be easier and more robust.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should serialize it with [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle
dict = {...}
tcp_send(pickle.dumps(dict))
```

And on the other end:

```
import pickle
dict = pickle.loads(tcp_recieve())
```

If the other end is not written in python, you can use a data serialization format, like [xml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxser/), [json](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) or [yaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML).

Comment: [pickle](https://davidhamann.de/2020/04/05/exploiting-python-pickle/) [is](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/03/exploiting-pickle/) [not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) [secure](https://intoli.com/blog/dangerous-pickles/)

Comment: with json you will face problems with encoding/decoding...

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to convert any Python object (including a dictionary) to a byte stream, which can then be sent over TCP and un-pickled on the receiving end.

Alternatively, you can use [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), which isn't dependent on the receiving end being a Python client.

Comment: Pickle might be a bad idea if the server is relatively liberal with who can send data to be unpickled - as the documentation states, "The pickle module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source."

Answer (score 5):

Pickle is considered insecure for sending data structures across connections as the object can never be trustfully reconstructed. This is why yaml, json or any other format is considered preferable.

Answer (score -1):

yes. its might be unsecured. but you can use https and send it thru post method. for get mehtod, try to consider encrypt pickle before sending

Comment: This question asks about TCP, HTTP is irrelevent