# How to send a json object using tcp socket in python

Tags: python, json, sockets, tcp

here is my python tcp client. I want to send a json object to the server.But I can't send the object using the sendall() method. how can I do this?

```
import socket
import sys
import json

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

m ='{"id": 2, "name": "abc"}'
jsonObj = json.loads(m)


data = jsonObj

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(jsonObj)


    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = sock.recv(1024)
finally:
    sock.close()

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

Comment: When you say 'I can't send the object', do you see any error? Or is the program stuck? Have you verified that a TCP server is listening at localhost:9999?

Comment: server is listening. and the following error appears..

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lochana/PycharmProjects/SocketClient/TCPClient.py", line 19, in <module>
    sock.sendall(jsonObj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
**TypeError: sendall() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not dict**

Comment: In that case, you need to serialize dict to string. Or pass the object 'm' to sendall instead of 'jsonObj'. (What is Serialization - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Answer (score 8):

Sending a dict with json like below worked in my program.

```
import socket
import sys
import json

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

#m ='{"id": 2, "name": "abc"}'
m = {"id": 2, "name": "abc"} # a real dict.


data = json.dumps(m)

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(bytes(data,encoding="utf-8"))


    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = sock.recv(1024)
    received = received.decode("utf-8")

finally:
    sock.close()

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

Answer (score 5):

Skip the `json.loads()` part. Send the json object as the json string and load it from the string at the TCP client.

Also check: [Python sending dictionary throught TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341823/python-sending-dictionary-throught-tcp)

Comment: No, you can not send the JSON object. You need to firstly serialize it

Comment: @LochanaThenuwara Send and sendall methods of socket accept string as parameter. Hence, you need to send data as string. In this case, data is json. At client end, convert it to string and at server, convert the received string to json.

Comment: when it's just a string returns *TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'* and when using with **json.loads** returns **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'**

Answer (score 1):

AS you can find out from [Python sending dictionary through TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341823/python-sending-dictionary-throught-tcp)
it better convert the JSON object  to a dictionary and using the following snippet

```
import json
data = json.load(open("data.json"))
 //or 
data = json.load('{"id": 2, "name": "abc"}')

type(data)
print(data[<keyFromTheJsonFile>])
```

You should serialize it with [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle
dict = {...}
tcp_send(pickle.dumps(dict))
```

And on the other end:

```
import pickle
dict = pickle.loads(tcp_recieve())
```

If the other end is not written in python, you can use a data serialization format, like [xml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxser/), [json](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) or [yaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML).